# Gauge freedom issues when numerically calculating overlap of states

Tags: computational-physics, topological-insulators, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Calculations of quantities of the form:

$$\langle\psi(k)|\partial_k|\psi(k) \rangle \ ,$$

require a smooth choice of the wave function $|\psi(k)\rangle$ over the whole BZ. This is not a problem. However, when numerically evaluating these objects, we look at:

$$\langle\psi(k)|\partial_k|\psi(k) \rangle \approx \frac{\langle\psi(k)|\psi(k+\Delta k) \rangle-\langle\psi(k)|\psi(k) \rangle}{\Delta k} \ .$$

Let's say the eigenvectors at $k$ and $k+\Delta k$ are obtained numerically. Any solution $|\psi \rangle$ to $H$ implies that $e^{i\phi}|\psi \rangle$ is also a solution.

This gauge freedom poses a problem when trying to obtain quantities like the [Berry curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_connection_and_curvature). How to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't this phase drop out in the integration?

Comment: The point is that the vectors are numerically obtained, as a result every vector gets a different phase. So you don't have a smooth choice of psi

Comment: You can probably be safe by forcing the value $\langle \psi(k)|\psi(k+\Delta k)\rangle$ to be real. Probably also safe to make it positive, for a sufficiently small $\Delta k$ and a sufficiently smooth evolution. But I see the point of the question, for arbitrary eigenvectors this phase does show up in the numerical approximation

Comment: A resolution to this problem is that if one defines the Berry curvature properly (much in the same way as how field strength is defined in lattice gauge theory), then there is no need to impose continuity condition on the phase of $|\psi(k)\rangle$, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.10248.pdf and references therein.

Comment: @MengCheng I keep reading people saying that if you just want to use the Berry phase as the OP states, then the problem OP states, namely that every $\left|nk\right>$ has a different phase, somehow does not matter, whereas if you compute Berry curvature, then you do need to align your phases, maybe by arbitrarily defining them somehow in practice. Would be nice to see a proof but maybe it is difficult. See comments in https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/how-to-calculate-the-berry-connection-difference?rq=1

Comment: Ah, the phase problem will just turn into a connection problem; these slides point out https://www.ens-lyon.fr/CBP/topiso/Talks_Online_files/Moore_Lyon2009.pdf

Comment: Allow me to specify. Consider the work by Fukui https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503172 here they argue that the eigenvectors need to be smooth to calculate the chern number. So they propose a gauge invariant method using link variables. Are there similar approaches. This one only seems to work for Chern number, I am calculating different but similar quantities

Answer (score 0):

Finding an everywhere smooth gauge is on the BZ is not always possible. Besides this, even if one can show that a smooth gauge exists in the BZ, it might be very hard to actually construct the gauge itself.

Luckily, this does not pose a problem in a lot of cases. For example, there are different gauge invariant quantities that one can compute without explicitly finding a smooth gauge. In [this paper](https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.1143/JPSJ.74.1674), the authors present an efficient numerical method to calculate the Berry curvature on a discretized BZ.

However, in certain cases, finding a smooth gauge numerically is an important aspect of the task to be solved. This problem requires different approaches depending on the dimensionality and symmetries of your model. Below, I present one of the simplest methods that guarantee a smooth gauge for a one dimensional BZ in the case of no symmetries. Let's assume that one already calculated a set of states $ \{\left|\psi_1 \right>, \left|\psi_2 \right>, \dots, \left|\psi_N \right>  \} $ numerically, meaning that their phases are random. You can think about this set as the set of states that you calculated in the discretized BZ as a function of the discrete wavenumber vector with the identification that $\left|\psi_i \right>$ belongs to wavenumber $k_i = \frac{2 \pi}{N} (i - 1) $, where $N$ is the size of the system. Note that one case define another state $\left|\psi_{N+1} \right> = \left|\psi_1 \right>$ due to the periodicity of the BZ. The gauge smoothing method goes as follows.

1. for each $k$ in range $(2, N+1)$, define a new state as
   \begin{equation}
   \left|\psi'_k \right> = \frac{\hat{P_{k-1}} \left|\psi_k \right>}{ |\hat{P_{k-1}} \left|\psi_k \right>|},
   \end{equation}
   where $\hat{P_{k-1}}$ is a projector defined as $\hat{P_{k-1}} = \left|\psi_k \right> \left<\psi_k \right|$ and $|.|$ denotes the norm of the state. With this, each $\psi'$ has norm $1$. This definition of $\psi'$ can be thought of as a parallel transport of the original state.
2. Note that $\psi'_{N+1}$ is almost identical to $\psi_1$ due to the periodicity of the BZ, but there can be a phase difference between them. This is expressed as
   \begin{equation}
   \left< \psi_1 | \psi_{N+1} \right> = e^{i \phi_B}, 
   \end{equation}
   where $\phi_B$ is the Berry-phase accumulated along the parallel transport.
3. To obtain a set of states with a smooth gauge, one needs to redistribute the Berry-phase evenly between the newly defined states $\psi'$. That is, for each $k$ in the range $(2,N)$, we define a new state
   \begin{equation}
   \psi''_k = \psi'_k e^{- i \frac{\phi_B}{N} (k-1)}.
   \end{equation}

With the above method, it is guaranteed that the set of states $\{\psi''_1, \psi''_2, \dots, \psi''_N \}$ will be equipped with a smooth, periodic gauge. This method works well in 1D independently of the Berry-phase accumulated along the parallel transport.

However, as I have already said, in a lot of usecases, finding a smooth gauge is not improtant because of the existence of efficient numerical algorithms with which one can compute gauge independent quantites in the BZ.

Hope this helps.