# Find smooth gauge numerically in the presence of symmetries

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-insulators, gauge

Let's assume a gapped two-band model in $2$D characterized by a Bloch-Hamiltonian $h(k_x,k_y)$ in the presence of reflection symmetry along the $x$ direction represented on the orbital degrees of freedom by $M_x = \sigma_z$. Here $\sigma_z$ is the $3$rd Pauli matrix and the Bloch-Hamiltonian satisfies
\begin{equation}
M_x h(k_x,k_y) M_x^{-1} = h(-k_x,k_y).
\end{equation}
At half filling, the system is an insulator due to the finite energy gap at all $(k_x,k_y)$ values in the BZ. Then, one can calculate the Chern number of the occupied band. Let's assume that this Chern number vanishes, meaning that in principle it is possible to find a smooth gauge for the eigenstates. Using a modification of the method presented in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/783691/226021), one can indeed construct a smooth gauge both for the occupied and unoccupied bands. However, this gauge is not symmetric upon $M_x$ in general.

How can one enforce numerically that the eigenstates will be equipped with a smooth gauge that is symmetric upon the action of $M_x$?